# Backbone button click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Having trouble getting a button click event registered with a backbone view.  The view itself displays just fine, with the correct data substituted into the template, but when I click the generated button, nothing happens.  Any ideas?

My view is defined as:

```
var IndividualNoteView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template:$("#indivNoteTemplate").html(),

    events: {
        'click .removeItem': "buttonClickHandler",
    },

    initialize : function (options) {
        console.log("Creating new indiv note view");

        this.options = options || {};
        this.gridster = this.options.gridster;
        this.noteModel = this.options.noteModel;
        this.row = this.options.row;
        this.col = this.options.col;
        this.el = $("#"+this.noteModel.get("noteId"));
        console.log("my domain- "+this.el.selector);
        this.noteModel.on('remove', this.destroy_view);
    },

    render: function(){
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        this.el = tmpl(this.noteModel.toJSON());
        this.gridster.add_widget(tmpl(this.noteModel.toJSON()));
    },

    buttonClickHandler : function(event){
        alert( $(event.currentTarget).text());

        return false;
    }
});
```

and my template (in my index.html) is defined as:

```
<script id="indivNoteTemplate" type="text/javascript">
<li id="<%= noteId%>">
   <div>Text: <%= text%></div> 
   <button class="removeItem">Remove</button></li>
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like a sequence issue. You may want to set the selector for your el when you pass in any initialization options: new IndividualNoteView({ el: '#' + modelInstance.get('noteId') });

Comment: @kdkavanagh, Have either of these answers helped to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `el` property backbone binds events to the views `el`.

for example:

`el: '#container'`

Or you could:

```
id: function()
{
    return this.noteModel.get('noteId');
}
```

and then use `this.$el` instead of doing `this.el = $("#"+this.noteModel.get("noteId"));` in the initialize function.

You would then not need to do `id="<%= noteId%>"` in the template since backbone will handle it for you.

Comment: hmm he is setting `el` in `initialize`. But even if `el` is not set, backbone create new `<div>` by default.

Answer (score 0):

At the time `initialize` is called your template has not been rendered so `this.el = $("#"+this.noteModel.get("noteId"));` is probably selecting nothing.

Furthermore, the Backbone.View creates the element for you, so you should not need to do this.

As per the [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render) your render function should probably look more like this

```
render: function(){
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.noteModel.toJSON()));
    this.gridster.add_widget(this.$el);
}
```

---

If you ever want to set the `.el` property manually you must call [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-137) to properly set up the Backbone View. You can see how this is [used internally here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-140).